# How to install P7M file into own MDM server?

Tags: ios, mobile, server, mdm

We have generated P7M File from iOS ABM portal and are not sure where we need to install it into MDM server to get connect with the device...

We have followed this link but didn't see right approach to install P7M file into MDM SERVER
https://it-training.apple.com/tutorials/deployment/dm055

Comment: You should follow the instructions provided by your MDM vendor

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.